# How do you build a tls.Certficate chain in Go?

Tags: ssl, go

I'm trying to configure a TLS server to return a Certificate *chain* on connection.

I want to create a [tls.Config](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Config), with a Certificate *chain* :

> ```
>     // Certificates contains one or more certificate chains
>     // to present to the other side of the connection.
>     // Server configurations must include at least one certificate
>     // or else set GetCertificate.
>     Certificates []Certificate
> ```

Assuming my chain is `root -> inter -> server`, I can load each certificate independently, and use a list, but only serverCert is sent to the SSL client.

I'm doing something along the lines of :

```
root, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("root.crt", "root.key")
inter, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("inter.crt", "inter.key")
server, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("server.crt", "server.key")

config := tls.Config{
   Certificates : []tls.Certificates{root, inter, server}
}
config.BuildNameFromCertificates()
```

Am I missing something obvious ? Does the order matter ?

Comment: The order does matter; try: `[]tls.Certificates{server, inter, root}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your server.crt file can contain the entire chain [plus you don't want your server to have the inter or root keys], in server.crt you can have

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[server cert]
-----END CERT-----
 ----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[inter cert]
-----END CERT-----
```

The root cert shouldn't be in the chain served from the server, just the server + intermediate[s].

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up understanding too.